# Isn't javascript regex lazy?

Tags: javascript, regex

Lets say I have the input value:

```
var input_value = "** foo ** bar **";
```

Then I run this:

```
input_value = input_value.replace(/(\*\*)([\S\s.]+)(\*\*)/g,replacer_markup);

function replacer_markup(match, p1, p2, p3, offset, string) {
  var pre = '';
  var post = '';
  if (p1 == '**')
  {
    pre = '<b>';
    post = '</b>';
  }
  return pre+p2+post
}
```

It will give me:

> **foo ** bar**

But instead I want to have:

> **foo** bar **

I want to have the smallest possible result. How can I achieve this?

Sorry for any spelling mistakes, I'm not a native speaker.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

`+` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy)  operator — it tells the engine to match as much as it can and still allows the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `+?` for a non-greedy match meaning "one or more — preferably as few as possible". Also, you can exclude the `.` from the character class.

```
([\S\s]+?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the regex non-greedy:

```
/(\*\*)([\S\s.]+?)(\*\*)/g
               -^-
```